# acess json data from another class

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing

I have downloaded `json` data and saved it in an dictionary in one class and then when I am trying to access in different value is showing as null. Code is as follows:

ClassA.m

```
NSDictionary *info=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

ClassB.m

```
Class *A=[ClassA alloc]init];
NSLog(%@,[[A.info objectForKey:@"msg"] objectForKey:@"cover_photo_id"]);
```

Comment: This code won't even compile. Please copy the code from your project. Otherwise it is quite hard to help you...

Comment: you should consider to implement a proper (singleton, maybe) model-layer in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating new instance of ClassA, so no information is stored in this instance.

For this code to work, you need to define info property in ClassA.h file

```
@property (strong) NSDictionary *info;
```

And after use this property after allocating a new ClassA instance. Like this:

```
self.info = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSLog(%@,[[A.info objectForKey:@"msg"] objectForKey:@"cover_photo_id"]);
```

Then this piece of code should work.